# Openldap not sending certificate on handshake

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I am trying to set up [PWM](https://github.com/pwm-project/pwm) for my OpenLDAP server on Ubuntu 16.04, but it fails to connect to LDAP with error

`Can not connect to remote server: 5059 ERROR_CERTIFICATE_ERROR (unable to read server certificates from host=ldap.example.com, port=389 error: Remote host closed connection during handshake)`

If I try to connect unencrypted, connection seems to be succesful, but setting up an account for PWM fails with `TLS confidentiality required`, which is intentional.

Authentication on clients and ldapsearch (with the switch -Z or -ZZ) work.
I have imported the certificate files to the clients and to Java on the server machine, as the certificate is self signed with openssl.

I tried to connect to LDAP with `openssl s_client -connect ldap.example:389 -showcerts -state -tls1_2` to check the certificate, but the connection terminates with no error messages and this output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:unknown state
SSL_connect:failed in unknown state
140394455615128:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:656:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1484029284
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Connection to port 443 outputs a certificate.
I quite honestly don't know what to do so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**389\TCP** is not LDAP SSL port by default. Port **636\TCP** commonly used for LDAP SSL (ldaps).

On the **389\TCP** port can be enabled STARTTLS (`ldapsearch` with the switch `-Z` or `-ZZ` use it). I'm not sure that OpenSSL s_client is able to implement STARTTLS for LDAP protocol.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the ports, but I am using TLS. The problem is not openssl but the PWM-application not being able to establish a TLS-connection. Sorry if the question is formatted unclearly. Is there another tool I could use to test the connectivity?

Comment: [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is the successor to SSL. It uses the same port as SSL.

Comment: As I see [here](https://github.com/pwm-project/pwm/wiki/General-Directory-Setup) PWM needs ldap**S** connection, so: 1) Check that you ldap accept SSL connection on 636\TCP; 2)  Configure PWM to connect with `ldaps://your.server:636` URI; 3) Import to Java your CA certificate as described in docs

Comment: do not mix two different technologies: TLS and STARTTLS

Comment: Oh, yes that was the problem, thank you very much. I just forgot that I had to enable ldaps in `/etc/default/slapd`